# ActionListenerを実装するクラスに引数を追加したら、JButtonを継承するクラスでコンパイルエラーになるのを解消したい。

Tags: java, swing

Java Swingにて、Lights Outのゲームアプリを作成する課題を行っているのですが、
ボタンを押下して左右上下の色を反転させるために、`ActionListener`を実装するクラスに引数を追加したところ、
`JButton`を継承するクラスの「**addActionListener(new LightsListener(this));** 」部分でコンパイルエラーが発生しました。

■エラー内容

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
> コンストラクター LightsListener(LightsButton) は未定義です
>
> at lightsOut.LightsButton.(LightsButton.java:17)
> at lightsOut.ButtonPanel.(ButtonPanel.java:22)
> at lightsOut.LightsOutJFrame.(LightsOutJFrame.java:33)
> at lightsOut.LightsOutJFrame.main(LightsOutJFrame.java:15)

引数が一致していないため発生していることは理解できているのですが、
`JButton`を継承するクラスにどのようにして引数を追加したらよいのかわからず、詰まっています。
お手数ですが、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

■`JButton`を継承するクラス

```
public class LightsButton extends JButton{
    
    /* buttonの初期値(今回は点灯なのでtrue) */
    private boolean buttonOn = true;
    
    /* JButtonの設定 */
    public LightsButton() {
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 60));
        addActionListener(new LightsListener(this));
        setEnabled(true);
    }
    
    /* on offの設定 */
    public void click() {
        if(buttonOn == true) {
            buttonOn = false;
            setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        }else {
            buttonOn = true;
            setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }
    }

}
```

■`ActionListener`を実装するクラス

```
public class LightsListener implements ActionListener{
    
    private LightsButton[][] buttonlist;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    
    /* 親buttonを呼び出し */
    public LightsListener(LightsButton button, LightsButton[][] buttonlist, int x, int y) {
        this.buttonlist = buttonlist;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    /* 親button内のclickメソッドを呼び出し */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        buttonlist[x][y].click();
        buttonlist[x + 1][y + 1].click();
    }

}
```

■親パネルクラス

```
public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel{
    
    LightsButton[][] button;
    
    /* Button */
    
    public ButtonPanel(){
        // buttonのレイアウト
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        
        // buttonの設定(3 x 3)
        button = new LightsButton[3][3];
        for(int i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
            for(int o = 0; o < button.length; o++) {
                button[i][o] = new LightsButton();
                add(button[i][o]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LightsListener`クラスの**コンストラクタ**に仮引数 (parameter) を追加したのであれば、それに対応する実引数 (argument) を渡してやればよいわけです。

`LightsButton`クラスの**コンストラクタ**内で`LightsListener`の**コンストラクタ**を呼び出しているので、`LightsButton`のコンストラクタ引数にも同じものを追加して転送します。

```
// LightsButton.java

    public LightsButton(LightsButton[][] buttonlist, int x, int y) {
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 60));
        addActionListener(new LightsListener(this, buttonList, x, y));
        setEnabled(true);
    }
```

```
// ButtonPanel.java
public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final int NUM_ROWS = 3;
    private static final int NUM_COLS = 3;

    private final LightsButton[][] buttonList = new LightsButton[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];

    public ButtonPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS));

        for (int x = 0; x < buttonList.length; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < buttonList[x].length; ++y) {
                buttonList[x][y] = new LightsButton(buttonList, x, y);
                add(buttonList[x][y]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ちなみに、「ボタンを押下して左右上下の色を反転させる」とのことですが、
`LightsListener.actionPerformed()`メソッドの実装が間違っています。
無条件に`buttonlist[x + 1][y + 1].click();`を実行すると、範囲外アクセスにより`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`例外がスローされるケースがあります。

配列のインデックスは0以上かつ各次元の長さ未満である必要があります。
あとは自分で考えてください。

Comment: Stack Overflowの使い方に関しては、次のリンクを参照してください。[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？ - ヘルプセンター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)